# How to add a comment to a Post using Parse and Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I've been working on an app that lets users post on the main timeline, and I've been working in the comment portion of the posts. Since I was stuck I followed a tutorial I found online:

http://shrikar.com/using-uitableview-and-footerview-to-implement-commenting-system-building-yik-yak-clone-part-3/

He implements the comment portion of an app, so I thought I could do something similar. 
However, after coding the comment portion like in the tutorial, the comments are not being displayed, neither the original post in the comments section.

On parse, I have a 'Posts' class that has the following tables:

- Users
- content (posts)
- likes (this a number)
- replies (# of comments)
- comments (which is an array that should hold all of the comments)

Here I attach the code that I have, and I also wonder if there's a way to keep the reply bar at the bottom of the screen, since it's attached to the table view. How can I get it to display the comments to the tableView?

Any help is appreciate it!

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class DetailViewContoller: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var postLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var commentTableView: UITableView!

var post: PFObject?
var commentView: UITextView?
var footerView: UIView?
var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0

var comments: [String]?
let FOOTERHEIGHT : CGFloat = 50;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    commentTableView.delegate = self

    /* Setup the keyboard notifications */
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)


    /* Setup the contentInsets */
    self.commentTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.commentTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero


    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
    /* Make sure the content doesn't go below tabbar/navbar */
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false


    if(post?.objectForKey("comments") != nil) {
        comments = post?.objectForKey("comments") as? [String]
    }
    println(post)
    println(post?.objectForKey("content"))
    self.postLabel.text = post?.objectForKey("content") as? String
}


func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    var info:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    var keyboardHeight:CGFloat =  keyboardSize.height - 40


    var animationDuration:CGFloat = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! CGFloat

    var contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardHeight, 0.0);
    self.commentTableView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.commentTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

}

func keyBoardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    self.commentTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.commentTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let count = comments?.count {
        return count
    }
    return 0
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = commentTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentTableViewCell
    cell.commentLabel?.text = comments![indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if self.footerView != nil {
        return self.footerView!.bounds.height
    }
    return FOOTERHEIGHT
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: commentTableView.bounds.width, height: FOOTERHEIGHT))
    footerView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 243.0/255, green: 243.0/255, blue: 243.0/255, alpha: 1)
    commentView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: commentTableView.bounds.width - 80 , height: 40))
    commentView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    commentView?.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)
    commentView?.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    commentView?.scrollsToTop = false

    footerView?.addSubview(commentView!)
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: commentTableView.bounds.width - 65, y: 10, width: 60 , height: 30))
    button.setTitle("Reply", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:  0/0.0, green: 179/255.0, blue: 204/255.0, alpha: 100.0/100.0)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.addTarget(self, action: "reply", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    footerView?.addSubview(button)
    commentView?.delegate = self
    return footerView
}

func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

    if (contentHeight == 0) {
        contentHeight = commentView!.contentSize.height
    }

    if(commentView!.contentSize.height != contentHeight && commentView!.contentSize.height > footerView!.bounds.height) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
            let myview = self.footerView
            println(self.commentView!.contentSize.height)
            println(self.commentView?.font.lineHeight)
            let newHeight : CGFloat = self.commentView!.font.lineHeight
            let myFrame = CGRect(x: myview!.frame.minX, y: myview!.frame.minY - newHeight , width: myview!.bounds.width, height: newHeight + myview!.bounds.height)
            myview?.frame = myFrame

            let mycommview = self.commentView
            let newCommHeight : CGFloat = self.commentView!.contentSize.height
            let myCommFrame = CGRect(x: mycommview!.frame.minX, y: mycommview!.frame.minY, width: mycommview!.bounds.width, height: newCommHeight)
            mycommview?.frame = myCommFrame

            self.commentView = mycommview
            self.footerView  = myview

            for item in self.footerView!.subviews {
                if(item.isKindOfClass(UIButton.self)){
                    let button = item as! UIButton
                    let newY = self.footerView!.bounds.height / 2 - button.bounds.height / 2
                    let buttonFrame = CGRect(x: button.frame.minX, y: newY , width: button.bounds.width, height : button.bounds.height)
                    button.frame = buttonFrame

                }
            }
        })

        println(self.footerView?.frame)
        println(self.commentView?.frame)
        contentHeight = commentView!.contentSize.height
    }
}

func reply() {
    post?.addObject(commentView!.text, forKey: "comments")
    post?.saveInBackground()
    if let tmpText = commentView?.text {
        comments?.append(tmpText)
    }
    commentView?.text = ""
    println(comments?.count)
    self.commentView?.resignFirstResponder()
    self.commentTableView.reloadData()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify if the data is stored properly in Parse or added to the local comments array properly?

Comment: The posts are online, I can see them on the database, but it's not saving anything to the array, nor I can see the DetailViewController post that I select

Comment: I verified running the code again and it works fine.. CAn you download the project from github and run it once?

Comment: Yes I did that, but it doesn't pass the data for some reason. It gives me an error at the prepareForSiegue, it crashes the whole app

Comment: So I managed to make it work, but now I get an error every one in a while and it says: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like the you are trying to access the array when its not present.. Can you give the snippet of your code?